# Elasticsearch - How to suggest by most often word used together?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Here is what i want to do:

I have a index with product descriptions, like:

- Sony KDL50W800C 50" 1080p Smart LED TV
- Samsung UN65JS8500 65" SUHD 4K Smart LED TV

When the user types "smart tv" I want the suggester to suggest:

- smart tv led
- smart tv sony

To logic behind this is:

- led is a common term used together with smart and tv
- sony is a common term used together with smart and tv

Is there any functionality in elasticsearch that would assist me with this?

I am using elasticsearch with elasticsearch.net and NEST.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, there's no exact query that would bring you back these results.

All I could suggest would be using completion suggester. You'd have to setup suggestions by yourself for these various combinations, unfortunately.